# RefreshControl sometimes does not hide and acts weirdly on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, pull-to-refresh

after upgrading from `react-native@0.26` activity indicator of `RefreshControl` sometimes appears in right corner of `ScrollView` on iOS.
I am using RefreshControl as correctly as documentation says:

```
...
<ScrollView
  style={styles.container}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
      onRefresh={this.onPullToRefresh}
    />
  }>
  <View>
    ...
  </View>
</ScrollView>
...
```

and here is what sometimes happening while not refreshing:

[image]

Now I am running `react-native@0.30.0` and this indicator is still annoying me.

Am I the only who faces this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by setting background to transparent color...

```
...
<ScrollView
      style={styles.container}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onPullToRefresh}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
        />
      }>
...
```

Comment: This problem still exists. React native presents us such weird problems sometimes.